# Reducing nested lists, a function to extend or append lists

Tags: python, json, list, append, extend

My question is two-fold.  First, is there a method in Python that will reduce redundant nesting in JSON objects/lists?  As a simple example, it would behave in the following way:

```
In [1]: reducer([1])
Out[1]: [1]
In [2]: reducer([[[1]]])
Out[2]: [1]
In [3]: reducer({"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [[{"id": 81}]]}})
Out[3]: {"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [{"id": 81}]}}
```

Second, is there a native `extend_or_append` function in python?  The function would behave as follows:

```
In [1]: tt = []
In [2]: extend_or_append(tt,1)
Out[2]: [1]
In [3]: extend_or_append(tt,[2,3,4,5])
Out[3]: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If this functionality does not exist, what is a robust way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Your second question is trivial.

```
def extend_or_append(this, that):
    if isinstance(that, list):
        this.extend(that)
    else:
        this.append(that)
    return this
```

The first is a tiny bit trickier

```
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

res = list(flatten([[[[[1]]]]]))
```

Comment: Note that `basestring` is gone in 3.x and you thus need to check against both `str` and `bytes`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Jakob.  The second function does not work in general.  For example, it will not reduce the following object `{"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [[{"id": 81}]]}}`.